# Problem with editing site

Tags: web-part

When I tried to edit a site with webpart I can't do anything in editing a page. And I can't save this page to (It can't be done on any web, and list with this subsite):

[image]

Comment: Seems like you have a javascript error on the page. What is the webpart that you have on the site?

Comment: This is a webpart write to my own.

Comment: How to find out Javascript on site ?

Comment: As @RobertLindgren mentioned, most probably you have a JS error. Check if you are getting any error on the page by opening Developer Console (F12).

Answer (score 2):

Did you check your permission on the site? It is possible that you have access on parent site but for this site the `permissions are broken`. Please goto `site settings->site permissions->Check Permissions`

You'll require `EDIT` permission to actually edit the page and then save it.

Comment: No it no permisions. I'm Site Collection administrator.